# Using "&" in a slug

Tags: url, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I have a slug field in the database which has been created from a name containing `&`:

```
name: Hansel & Gretel
slug: hansel-&-gretel
```

Doctrine removes from the name characters which are not url-friendly. Well, `&` is definitely url-friendly.

Now, when I generate a link to the fairytale with symfony's `link_to()` I get:

```
http://myfairytalesite.ft/tale/hansel-%26amp%3B-gretel
```

So before the `&` gets url-encoded it gets changed to a HTML entity.

When I navigate to this URL I get 404 error because the slug is only url-decoded and the route (sfDoctrineRoute) tries to find an object with the slug `hansel-&amp;-gretel` which obviously does not exist in the database.

**My question: what can I do about it?**

The name is imported from an external source so I  can't change it manually.

I thought of adding a `html_entities_decode` to the action where I use the slug but it feels like attaching a wing to a plane with duct-tape...

I even tried to dig into the Symfony's internals and see what could I change there and I went so deep I was afraid I'm going to wake up the Balrog but couldn't find anything interesting. :/

Has anyone had a similar problem? Can it be a Sf or Doctrine bug?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid this issue, I replace any & symbols as well as & amp; with an "and" when I save my slugs.

E.g.

```
hansel-and-gretel
```